# Can i specify different notifications within the same class extended broadcast receiver

Tags: android

I have specified 2 proximity alerts for 2 different points.
For each proximity alert i have specified an eventID as you can see in the following code. For each proximity alert(for each point) i want differrent notification sound. The main question is how i can create different notifications (notifications sound) within the same class.

Here is the code i have used.

```
private void setProximityAlert(double lat, double lon, final int eventID,int requestCode) {

            float radius = 10f;         

            long expiration =-1; 
            LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();                       
            Intent intent = new Intent(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION);                
            intent.putExtra(ProximityAlert.EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, eventID);
            intent.putExtra(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION, extras); 
            PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), requestCode , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                locManager.addProximityAlert(
                    lat, 
                    lon, 
                    radius, 
                    expiration, 
                    proximityIntent 
               );     
            }

 private void initialiseReceiver()
        {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION); 
            registerReceiver(new ProximityAlert(), filter);
        }
```

In the BroadcastReceiver class i have the notification in the following code

```
public class ProximityAlert extends BroadcastReceiver {

            public static final String EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA = "EventIDIntentExtraKey";




            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                int eventID = intent.getIntExtra(EVENT_ID_INTENT_EXTRA, 1);



                switch(+eventID) {


                case '1':

                    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

                    Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

                    if (entering) {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
                    }

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
                        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);   

                        Notification notification = new Notification(); 

                        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Proximity Alert!", "ειναι σωστο αυτο που εκανεσ", pendingIntent);

                        notificationManager.notify(1, notification);

                        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_menu_notifications;
                        notification.sound =  Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/File/sdcard/introduction_file.mp3");

                        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
                        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

                        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
                        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
                        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

                    break;

                case '2':

                    String key1 = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

                    Boolean entering1 = intent.getBooleanExtra(key1, false);

                    if (entering1) {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
                    }

                    NotificationManager nnotificationManager = 
                        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                        PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);  

                        Notification notification1 = new Notification();    

                        notification1.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Proximity Alert!", "ειναι σωστο αυτο που εκανεσ", pendingIntent1);

                        nnotificationManager.notify(2, notification1);

                        notification1.icon = R.drawable.ic_menu_notifications;
                        notification1.sound =  Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/File/sdcard/Carter_Lane.mp3");

                        notification1.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                        notification1.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
                        notification1.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

                        notification1.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
                        notification1.ledOnMS = 1500;
                        notification1.ledOffMS = 1500;


                    break;
```

I have used the switch method so, for different eventID the programme should change notification. but it does not work. can you help me
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `PendingIntent`.

Quoting the documentation:

> If the creating application later re-retrieves the same kind of PendingIntent (same operation, same Intent action, data, categories, and components, and same flags), it will receive a PendingIntent representing the same token if that is still valid

Since you have the same operation (`getBroadcast()`) and the same `Intent` routing pieces each time, there is only one `PendingIntent`.

Rather than setting the action to be `PROXIMITY_INTENT_ACTION`, make it be unique for each distinct proximity alert. If you use the component constructor on `Intent` (i.e., `new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class)`), the different action strings will not impact the routing of the broadcast.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for you answer. I would like to ask how can i create different notifications for each point. the first step is what you told me before to create different PendingIntent for each point and to create intent(this, MyReceiver.class). But on broadcast receiver class (public class ProximityAlert extends BroadcastReceiver) {...... how can i specify differrent notifications sound. thank you very much

Comment: @amz: Use different IDs and different `Notification` objects for your calls to the `notify()` method.

Comment: Sorry again..I used the switch method. If you see the code, for each event ID(which can be 1 or 2) i have created different notifications objects and register the object to the notification manager with different NotifyID. but when i go to test the application it does not work. it does not create any notification. Do you have or can you suggest me any link that i can get more information about notifications. thank you very much